# Deploy static website to Google Cloud made with Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, static, gcloud, gatsby

I have been trying to deploy my static app made with Gatsby on Google Cloud Platform.

My trouble is with the app.yaml file.

- Here's what I've done so far:

  1. Made a Gatsby project.
  2. Gatsby build.
  3. Uploaded the public folder to a GCS bucket.
  4. Copied it to the Google Cloud Shell using the following command: gsutil rsync -r gs://static-site-test ./gatsby-test
  5. cd gatsby-test
  6. Created an app.yaml file:
  7. gcloud app deploy

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: public/
  upload: public/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: public/static
```

- The first page of the application loads fine, but any links to other pages do not work.
- I think my trouble is with the app.yaml, I don't understand how to fill it out properly.
- Here's my public folder:
  [image: img]

I have multiple pages.

Both the page-2 and the about folders contain an index.html file.

Any thoughts?

I have tried the following:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: public/index.html
  upload: public/index.html
- url: /page-2
  static_dir: public/page-2/index.html
```

also

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: public/index.html
  upload: public/index.html
- url: /page-2
  upload: public/page-2/index.html
```

Although I hope this method isn't right because if I have multiple pages, this can become cumbersome.

Here's my index page:

```js
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Image from "../components/image"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Home" />
    <h1>Hi people</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your new Gatsby site.</p>
    <p>Now go build something great.</p>
    <div style={{ maxWidth: `300px`, marginBottom: `1.45rem` }}>
      <Image />
    </div>
    <Link to="/page-2/">Go to page 2</Link>

    <Link to="about">Go to about</Link>
    <p>paragrap h</p>
    <div style={{ color: `purple` }}>
      <h1>Hello Gatsby!</h1>
      <p>What a word</p>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x200" alt="" />
    </div>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

My results were that I could only access the index.html page, but when clicking the links, I got a "Page not found error".

### Edit:

I changed my app.yaml but now i'm having trouble with my images

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

#site root
- url: /
  static_files: public/index.html
  upload: public/index.html

# page-2
- url: /page-2/
  static_files: public/page-2/index.html
  upload: public/page-2/index.html

# Page not found
- url: /.*
  static_files: public/404/index.html
  upload: public/404/index.html

  # image files
- url: /(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: public/\1
  upload: public/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
```

The hierarchy is as follows:

\PUBLIC\STATIC

├───6d91c86c0fde632ba4cd01062fd9ccfa

│   ├───59139

│   ├───af144

│   ├───b5207

│   ├───d3809

│   ├───e22c9

│   └───fdbb0

└───d

And inside those random folders are the images.

I also made that my images show directly into the public/ folder but still doesn't work.

Here's how i'm using the images:

```js
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Image from "../components/image"
import SEO from "../components/seo"
import logo from "../images/gatsby-icon.png"
import logo2 from "../../static/secondicon.png"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Home" />
    <h1>Hi people</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your new Gatsby site.</p>
    <p>Now go build something great.</p>
    <div style={{ maxWidth: `300px`, marginBottom: `1.45rem` }}>
      <Image />
    </div>
    <Link to="/page-2/">Go to page 2</Link>

    <Link to="about">Go to about</Link>
    <p>paragrap h</p>
    <div style={{ color: `purple` }}>
      <h1>Hello Gatsby!</h1>
      <p>What a word</p>
      <img src={logo} alt="" />
      <p>Second icon:</p>
      <img src={logo2} alt="" />
    </div>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

here's the deployment: https://static-site-test-256614.appspot.com/

Am i just trying to deploy the wrong way? should i just use something else for this?

Comment: Why don't you serve the Gatsby site directly from the storage bucket instead? I've done this for a site of mine with little issue. [link to gcloud docs on hosting static site](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website)

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. I know those docs, and i haven't been able to do it without a domain. That's why i would like to use the engine, it gives me a free domain to test. Is there a way to connect the two?

Comment: Just creating a bucket does not work. At least i can't make it work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following app.yaml file should work correctly with the Gatsby quickstart [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54616748/proper-app-yaml-handlers-configuration-for-google-app-engine-for-a-static-html-w):

```
runtime: python27
api_version: '1'
threadsafe: true

handlers:

  - url: /
    static_files: public/index.html
    upload: public/index.html

  - url: /((.*\/)*[^\/]+\.[^\/]+)$
    static_files: public/\1
    upload: public/.*

  - url: /(.*)$
    static_files: public/\1/index.html
    upload: public/.*/index.html
```

You can refer to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54616748/proper-app-yaml-handlers-configuration-for-google-app-engine-for-a-static-html-w) for more examples of app.yaml configurations when serving static websites and the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) for all the app.yaml elements.

Comment: # 404 for all other websites

- url: /.*

does this mean that for any other endpoint, you get the 404?

Also,  images don't work. What else do i need?

Comment: The last URL handler simply shows the 404 html website in case someone types in something like your-project.appspot.com/whateverisnotdefined or any other handler that is not defined on your website. The images won't work if you have them as static files on your website folder. You'll need to upload them as well. Simply look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609000/serve-static-file-using-app-engine) and change the ```# image files``` according to your own folder structure.

Comment: ```
- url: /(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: public/\1
  upload: public/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
```

I tried it this way, the thing is the images are in the public/static folder but then there are random folders generated by gatsby.
I made it so that my images show directly into public/ but it still doesn' work with what i have in my app.yaml.

Formatting for the code is weird here, so im putting it in the main post.

Comment: Am i just trying to deploy the wrong way? should i just use something else for this?

Comment: The ideal solution would be to use GCS as suggested by @Derek Nguyen.If you put your images on the public/ folder then you would also need to change your index.html file so that the <img src=correct/path.. tag is properly set.

Comment: I gave up on GCloud, and went to AWS S3, it worked on my first try... I don't know why it didn't on gcloud.

Comment: I updated the app.yaml file on my answer to include a regex on the URL handler to comply with all the directory structure of the Gatsby [quickstart](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/quick-start/) (which is very similar to yours). I was based on the information provided on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54616748/proper-app-yaml-handlers-configuration-for-google-app-engine-for-a-static-html-w). I tested it and the astronaut picture loads correctly.