# Managing handlers when storing React+Gatsby static App on GCP

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, gatsby

My React App is already running on GCP engine. Navigation and all the pages look fine but direct links are causing issues - for example, if I open myWebsite.com/vacancies, I'll get the error log saying that **Static file referenced by handler not found: public/vacancies//index.html**.
Here's my app.yaml handlers config:

```
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: public/index.html
    upload: public/index.html

  - url: /((.*\/)*[^\/]+\.[^\/]+)$
    static_files: public/\1
    upload: public/.*

  - url: /(.*)$
    static_files: public/\1/index.html
    upload: public/.*/index.html
```

The workaround is opening the page like this **myWebsite.com/vacancies/index.html**, but I'd like to find more smooth solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you deploying your app? App engine? Can you provide a little more details so that it will be easier to solve your problem.

Comment: @BakulMitra could you be more concrete, which details?

Comment: Like where are you deploying your app? In which google platform? whether it's App Engine or any other in particular?

Comment: @BakulMitra yes, App Engine

Comment: @LirysJH posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my case:

```
  - url: /(.*)\/$
    static_files: public/\1/index.html
    upload: public/.*index.html

  - url: /(.*)$
    static_files: public/\1/index.html
    upload: public/.*/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is mainly caused by a problem in the app.yaml file, it can be caused if static file handlers redirects to a file that does not exist or the file name mentioned is incorrect. Please make sure you are using an updated version for the language and the name mentioned in the file is correct.

You can refer to the public [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref) where reference for the App.yaml file is provided, you can also refer to the stackoverflow answers for the [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54616748/proper-app-yaml-handlers-configuration-for-google-app-engine-for-a-static-html-w) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489405/deploy-static-website-to-google-cloud-made-with-gatsby) where a brief description for the app.yaml handlers configuration has been provided for the static website.